# ReactDOMServer.renderToString() returning empty html

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

im trying to render react on the server, while everthing works. when i go to view page source the main `<div id='root'></div>` is empty.

i tried renderToStaticMarkup() but its not working as well.

here is a picture of the view page source:

[image]

frontend/server.js:

```
const PORT = 3000
const app = express()

const router = express.Router()

const { persistor, store } = createPersistor()

const serverRenderer = (req, res, next) => {

  app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
  })

  const context = {}

  fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return res.status(500).send('An error occurred')
    }
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">
        ${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
              <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <App />
              </PersistGate>
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider>
        )}
        </div>`
      )
    )
  })
}

router.use('^/$', serverRenderer)

router.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'))
)

app.use(router)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SSR running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Look like you have some content inside root id, Does your `<App/>` have any content at the time it gets rendered?

Comment: @RyanLe yes all the content of the app is an <App /> component